# Why does one compute an outer product of marginal distributions (of contingency table) instead of splitting data up completely equally?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, chi-squared-distribution

I am studying about the chi-squared test statistic and came across the following code.

```
data  <- c(12,13,24,14,22,11,8,6,11,14,6,7) # data
obs <-  matrix(data, nrow=3, byrow = TRUE) # structure in a matrix
obs <- as.table(obs) # transform into table
dimnames(obs) <- list('Exam' = c('passed', 'not passed', 'not participated'),
                      'HomeWork' = c('None', '<0.5', '>0.5', 'all')) # name axes
obs

margin.row <- margin.table(obs, 1) # row-wise
margin.row
# rowSums(obs)

margin.col <- margin.table(obs, 2) # column-wise
margin.col
# colSums(obs)


expected <- outer(rowSums(obs), colSums(obs), FUN = '*') / sum(data)
expected 

expected <- outer(rowSums(obs), colSums(obs), FUN = '*') / sum(data)
expected 

mosaicplot(obs, main = "Observations")
```

I wonder why one does the outer product instead of doing `sum(obs)/(3*4)` which would split the data up completely equally and then compute the chi-squared statistic (observed-expected)^2/expected

Like this:

```
expected_alt <- matrix(rep(sum(data)/12, 12), byrow = T, ncol = 4)
dimnames(expected_alt) <- list('Exam' = c('passed', 'not passed', 'not participated'),
                      'HomeWork' = c('None', '<0.5', '>0.5', 'all')) # name axes

mosaicplot(expected_alt)
```

When one does, one gets a lower chi-squared test statistic. This means, it is not as clearly significantly different, right? The lower the test statistic the closer it will be to some critical value (coming from the table for some significance level). So it seems to be more conservative.

Back to the main question:
=> Why does not split the data equally?

Maybe the 'alternative way' computes a test statistic for something different. but i wouldn't know why. I guess I just don't get the reason behind the use of `outer()`.

Thank you for any help.